# importing compressed (gzip) data from s3 to hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, hdfs

i have bunch of .gzip files in s3://mybucket/file/*.gzip.

I am loading into a table using:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

create external table db.tablename(col1 dataype,col1 dataype,col1 dataype,col1     dataype) PARTITIONED BY (col datatype)
CLUSTERED BY (col2) SORTED BY (col1,col2) into 200 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3://mybucket/file';
```

It creates the table but doesn't load the data from s3 to hive/hdfs.

Any help is appreciated?

thanks
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

I think your files present in s3://mybucket/file/ is not organized in correct directory structure for Hive partitions. I suggest that you create an external table without partitions and buckets on s3://mybucket/file/ and then write hive query to read data from this table and write to your partitioned/bucketed table.